# How do you rescale the height of a histogram?

Tags: matlab

I am having trouble plotting a histogram of the `x`-values of my data points together with a line showing the relationship between `x` and `y`, mainly because the scale in the `y` direction of the histogram is not of the same magnitude as the scale in the line plot. For example:

```
% generate data
rng(1, 'twister')
x = randn(10000,1);
y = x.^2

% plot line, histogram, then histogram and line.
subplot(3,1,1)
scatter(x, y, 1, 'filled')
ax = gca;
maxlim = max(ax.XLim); % store maximum y-value to rescale histogram to this value

subplot(3,1,2)
h = histogram(x, 'FaceAlpha', 0.2)

subplot(3,1,3)
scatter(x, y, 1, 'filled')
hold on
h = histogram(x, 'FaceAlpha', 0.2)
```

Produces the following:

[image]

where the line chart is completely obscured by the histogram.

Now, one might naively try to rescale the histogram using:

```
h.Values = h.Values/max(h.Values) * maxlim;
```

which gives

```
You cannot set the read-only property 'Values' of Histogram.
```

Alternatively one can get the bin counts using `histcounts`, but as far as I can tell, the `bar` function does not allow one to set the face alpha or have other configurability as per the call to `histogram`.

Comment: You can change the face alpha of a bar chart (https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/243589) and so using `histc` is likely the smarter way to go.

Comment: thanks, can the other properties configured by `histogram` also be accessible in a similarly arcane way?

Comment: Very likely. Another option for you is to plot the line chart or the histogram on a secondary y axis

Comment: Like how I have done it in a subplot, or some other way?

Comment: no done another way. See MATLAB docs on [Create Chart with Two y-Axes](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/plotting-with-two-y-axes.html). This way you line plot and your histogram can be plotted with different scales

Comment: thanks, that is a great solution but that only works with `2016a`.

Comment: You could always add another axis - try this sort of approach http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6573862/two-y-axis-with-the-same-x-axis

Comment: Your first link no longer works after 2014a: see http://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/213991-matlab-put-transparancy-on-a-bar-plot

Comment: @Dan: `histc` is [deprecated](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/replace-discouraged-instances-of-hist-and-histc.html) and has been for several releases now.

Comment: I recommend reading through the documentation for `histogram` and `histcounts`. They can do a lot of things. Have you tried any of the `'Normalization'` options? It's not clear to me if you want to reduce the height of your histogram or increase the height of your scatter plot. You can easily [modify `histogram` object properties](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histogram-object.html).

Comment: I would like to reduce the height of my histogram, using the rescale factor `maxlim / max(h.Values)`.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments there are several solutions that depend on the version of Matlab you are using. To restate the problem, the `histogram` function allows you to control many graphics properties like transparency, but only gives you a limited number of options to change the height of the bars. With `histcounts` you can get the bar heights and rescale them however you want, but you must plot the bars yourself.

**First option: use `histogram`**

As you cannot rescale the histogram heights, you must plot them on separate axis.

From release `2016a` and onwards, you can use `yyaxis left` for the scatter plot and `yyaxis right` for the histogram, see [Matlab documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/plotting-with-two-y-axes.html):

Prior to this one must manually create and set separate `y`-axis. Although I have not found a good simple example of this, this is perhaps the most relevant answer here: [plot two histograms (using the same y-axis) and a line plot (using a different y-axis) on the same figure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28334462/plot-two-histograms-using-the-same-y-axis-and-a-line-plot-using-a-different-y)

**Using `histcounts` and manually creating a bar chart**

Using my example, we can get counts as follows:

```
[Values, Edges] = histcounts(x);
```

And rescaling:

```
Values = Values / max(Values) * maxlim;
```

and finding centres of bars:

```
bar_centres = 0.5*(Edges(1:end-1) + Edges(2:end));
```

Up to release `2014a`, bar charts had a 'children' property for the patches that allows transparency to be controlled, e.g.:

```
% plot histogram
b1 = bar(bar_centres,Values);
% change transparency
set(get(b1,'Children'),'FaceAlpha',0.3)
```

After `2014a` bar charts no longer have this property, and to get around it I plot the patches myself using the code from this [mathworks q&a](http://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/213991-matlab-put-transparancy-on-a-bar-plot), replicated here:

```
function ptchs = createPatches(x,y,offset,c,FaceAlpha)
%createPatches.m
% This file will create a bar plot with the option for changing the
% FaceAlpha property. It is meant to be able to recreate the functionality
% of bar plots in versions prior to 2014b. It will create the rectangular
% patches with a base centered at the locations in x with a bar width of
% 2*offset and a height of y.

% Ensure x and y are numeric vectors
validateattributes(x,{'numeric'},{'vector'});
validateattributes(y,{'numeric'},{'vector'});
validateattributes(c,{'char'},{'scalar'});
%#TODO Allow use of vector c

% Check size(x) is same as size(y)
assert(all(size(x) == size(y)),'x and y must be same size');

% Default FaceAlpha = 1
if nargin < 5
    FaceAlpha = 1;
end
if FaceAlpha > 1 || FaceAlpha <= 0
    warning('FaceAlpha has been set to 1, valid range is (0,1]');
    FaceAlpha = 1;
end

ptchs = cell(size(x)); % For storing the patch objects

for k = 1:length(x)
    leftX = x(k) - offset; % Left Boundary of x
    rightX = x(k) + offset; % Right Boundary of x
    ptchs{k} = patch([leftX rightX rightX leftX],...
        [0 0 y(k) y(k)],c,'FaceAlpha',FaceAlpha, ...
        'EdgeColor', 'none');
end




end
```

I made one change: that is, imposed the no edge condition. Then, it is perfectly fine to use:

```
createPatches(bin_centres, Values, 1,'k', 0.2)
```

to create the bars.